# GetFeatureInfo returns "no layers queryable"

Tags: wms, getfeatureinfo

I'm not able to get information with "GetFeatureInfo" request. I'm getting following reply:

"Either no layer was queryable, or no layers were specified using QUERY_LAYERS"

I made sure that my WMS (https://www.geoservice.apps.be.ch/geoservice2/services/a42geo/a42geo_hoehenwms_d_fk/MapServer/WMSServer?service=WMS&version=1.1.1&request=GetCapabilities&) is set to be "Queryable".

Using QGIS I manage to get attributes without a problem.

Are there any settings in my service that I may forget to enable in order to use the request "GetFeatureInfo"?

Comment: This question was tagged with geoserver, but the service in question 'my service` is not GeoServer it's ESRI. geoserver is not a generic term, but the name of a software product.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question or issue actually is.  The question question is what about server settings  because of an error in a GetFeatureInfo request, but the OP says that in QGIS they can get attributes, (and so can I) from a GetFeatureInfo request so the service is correctly configured.

Answer (score 5):

As is explained in the [documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/cascaded/wms.html#features) `getFeatureInfo` requests are only supported if the remote server supports `application/vnd.ogc.gml` as the info format.

> WMS GetFeatureInfo requests will be passed to the remote WMS. If the remote WMS supports the `application/vnd.ogc.gml` format the request will be successful.

Comment: My wms unfortunately doesn't support this format. Thank you for your replay!